# Core Data: Cascading 1:1 Relationships

Tags: core-data

Scenario: Cascading 1:1 Relationship as shown below.

I merely want to have an inverse relationship amongst a few entities, based on the userID field.

Questions:

1) How does the relationships know which field to link to?

 All I did was indicate target and give the relationship a distinct name.

 If the relationship is independent on the supplied userID, then I assume such field is superfluous; correct?

2) You'll notice that I need two (2) relationships: userID & userID2.

Essentially I merely want to link all common userId values across files.   Is this the correct setup?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Core Data isn't a relational database, therefore you don't need a specific field to create a relationship between objects.**

Typically you use relationships to model what would be a property on an object.

If you want `UserConfigurations`, `UserCredentials`, etc. to be related to a `User` then you should create a relationship between `User` and each of the user specific objects.

Then you can access a users configuration somewhat like this:

```
user.configurations
```

If you have set up *inverse* relationships, which Core Data recommends, you can also access the `User` from the `UserConfigurations` object. That allows you to access other parts of the object graph easily, e.g. you could access a users events from a users configuration:

```
configuration.user.events
```

This way you don't need relationships between the different objects that are related to a user.

Your data model should look similar to this:

[image]